# context passed in a constructor is showing error

Tags: java, android-studio

I am beginner in android development .I was trying to make custom array adapter to display something.
but when I am passing the arguments from main activity it shows an error in context
like required type-context and provided Main activity..

**This is my first question friends so please help me out**
**main activity.java**

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ArrayList<text> arr= new ArrayList<>();
        arr.add(new text(4,5));
        textadapter extadapter=new textadapter(this,arr);
        ListView listView=findViewById(R.id.list_item);
        listView.setAdapter(extadapter);

    }
}
```

**custom arrayadapter**

```
 public class textadapter extends ArrayAdapter {


    public textadapter(@NonNull Context context,ArrayList<text> arrayList) {
        super(context,0,arrayList);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView==null){
            convertView= LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list,parent,false);
        }
        text a= (text) getItem(position);
        TextView t=convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        TextView T1=convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        t.setText(a.getText());
        T1.setText(a.getStext());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: `super(context,0,arrayList);`  remove zero from this line `super(context,arrayList);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change getContext() in getView() method in TextAdapter class into context and make a variable called mContext as you are already passing Main Activity Context into Adapter Constructor.

```java
public class textadapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private Context context;

   public textadapter(@NonNull Context context,ArrayList<text> arrayList) {
      super(context,arrayList);
      this.context = context;
   }

  @NonNull
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView==null){
        convertView= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list,parent,false);
    }
    text a= (text) getItem(position);
    TextView t=convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
    TextView T1=convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
    t.setText(a.getText());
    T1.setText(a.getStext());
    return convertView;
}
```